# StackOverflow Error in Recursive Binary Search Code

Tags: java, search

I have written this code for "Recursive Binary Search". I get a `StackOverflowError` at the marked line. However, I didn't use `(l+h)/2` as the `mid` which may cause a stack overflow for large values.

```
public class RecursiveMethod
{
    public static int RecursiveBinarySearch(int[] array, int l, int h, int x)
    {
        l = 0;
        h = array.length - 1;

        while (l<=h)
        {
            int mid = l + (h-l)/2;

            if (x == array[mid])
                return mid;
            else if (x < array[mid])
                return RecursiveBinarySearch(array, l, mid-1, x); // overflow here
            else // last possibility: x > array[mid]
                return RecursiveBinarySearch(array, mid+1, h, x);
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int[] a =
                  {2, 8, 12, 14, 16, 19, 24, 28, 31, 33,    // 0 - 9
                   39, 40, 45, 49, 51, 53, 54, 56, 57, 60,  // 10-19
                   63, 69, 77, 82, 88, 89, 94, 96, 97};     // 20-28

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            System.out.print("(" + a + "," + a[i] + ")" + "  ");

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(RecursiveBinarySearch(a, 0, a.length, 1) + " ");
        System.out.print(RecursiveBinarySearch(a, 0, a.length, 26) + " ");
        System.out.print(RecursiveBinarySearch(a, 0, a.length, 85) + " ");
        System.out.print(RecursiveBinarySearch(a, 0, a.length, 99) + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Improved formatting, clarified the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you're using a while loop in you recursive function. You should change your code as follows and it should work.

```
public class RecursiveMethod {
    public static int RecursiveBinarySearch(int[] array, int l, int h, int x) {
        if (h>=l)
            int mid = l + (h-l)/2;

        if (x == array[mid])
            return mid;
        else if ( l == h)
            return -1;
        else if (x < array[mid])
            return RecursiveBinarySearch(array, l, mid-1, x);
        if (x > array[mid])   // last possibility: x > array[mid]
            return RecursiveBinarySearch(array, mid+1, h, x);
    }
}
```

EDIT
And as Brett Okken pointed out, you shouldn't be overwriting your l,h within the call.

Comment: This will throw stack overflow as well as it also resets `l` and `h` during each recursive call.

Comment: Sorry that is true as well, but the fact is he doesn't need the while loop either. I fixed my solution.

Comment: @krisdestruction even with this new one (without assigning value to **l** and **h**), I get "stack over flow" error.

Comment: @Hengameh New l and h values are set when `RecursiveBinarySearch` is recursed.

Comment: Not sure why, but my mid calculation disappeared in my last edit after copying from Sublime. Anyways added it back.

Comment: @Hengameh Personally, I'd change your mid calculation to `int mid = (l + h ) / 2;` just for clarity sake.

Comment: @Hengameh Do you still get it? I made a few edits since your post. If so, where is it erring out now?

Comment: @krisdestruction - Yeah, I worked finally. I added this condition also: **if (h>=l)**

Comment: before *`int mid = l + (h-l)/2;`* , so it will recur till *`h>=l`* is satisfied. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @Hengameh Ah I see, thank you that's an edge case and I updated it. Personally I wouldn't call recursion that way `mid+1` and `mid-1`. I'd do it as `mid` for both calls and use an if statement for termination right as it enters the last recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You are always setting `l` and `h` and ignoring the args. So when you recurse, you are starting at the exact middle again:

```
public static int RecursiveBinarySearch(int[] array, int l, int h, int x) {
  l = 0;
  h = array.length -1;
```

Comment: Err l and h are recursive bounds though and he does call it with either one of them and sets the midpoint to the other :/

Comment: @krisdestruction He can call the  methods with whatever values for `l` and `h`, it does not matter. They are immediately reassigned to `0` and the number of values.

Comment: I agree, but at the same time, the rest of the algo doesn't work or if it does, it's inefficient. There's no use of the while loop within the call.